# Endpoint Not found MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm working with a very weird endpoint,
Now the data I post to my endpoint is the `scorecardId` and the `DashboardConfig` and the rest of my data is populated via the backend, which is the `UserId` and the `DateCreated`, Now I need to do a get request for the specific user and I did something like this:

```
#region Public Methods
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetbyUserID")]
        [ValidateModel]
        public IHttpActionResult GetbyUserID(Guid UserID)
        {
            UserID = this.GetUserId();
            var config = _prefentialDashboardConfigService.GetByUserID(UserID);
            return Ok(config);
        }
```

My model:

```
    public Guid ScorecardId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string DashboardConfig { get; set; }
```

My CRUD:

```
        public PrefentialDashboardConfig GetByUserID(System.Guid UserId, params string[] includes)
    {
        return Repository.SingleOrDefault<PrefentialDashboardConfig>(config => config.UserId == UserId, includes);
    }
}
```

My ICRUD:

```
        T SingleOrDefault<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params string[] includes) where T : class;
```

And in my front end I just called the get request but it gives me a 404 resource not found error. I call my end point like this in knockout:

```
var test = PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.GetbyUserID();
//For testing purposes
console.log("You got it right!" + JSON.stringify(test));
```

What would be the best way to get my data to the frontend console by the UserId which is taken from my backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only guessing, you are probably not passing the UserId when you are doing the http get request.

```
var test = PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.GetbyUserID();
```

probably should be

```
var test = PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.GetbyUserID(5);
```

check the network tab in the browser dev tools to make sure that there are parameters are being passed to the backend